# How to plot a Spiral function with a function inside of another one?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot an Spiral graph that is supposed to look like this...

[image]

It is the result of a function u_c(t) inside i(t).

```
u_c(t) = 5 + exp(-1266.77*x) * (-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x)) + 10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x)))
i(t) = exp(-1266.77*x) * (6.3*cos(deg(5508.55*x)) + 1.5*sin(deg(5508.55*x))
```

I can plot both of them, but i cannot Plot u_c(t) inside i(t) and it to look like the example...

Any help would be appreciated.

here is my code for u_c(t) and i(t) and the mess i did with i(u_c(t)).

```
%%%u_c(t)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title = {Verlauf der Kondensatorspannung nach Öffnen des Schalters},
    xlabel = {$t$ in s}, 
    ylabel= {$u_C(t)$ in V},
     xmin = 0, xmax = 0.0050,
     ymin = 0, ymax = 18,
    xtick distance = 0.0005,
    ytick distance = 2,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!0.25},
    width = \textwidth,
    height = 0.5\textwidth]
        \addplot[
        domain = 0:0.005,
        samples = 300,
        smooth,
        thick,
        blue,] {5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x)))};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


%%%i(t)

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title = {Verlauf des Gesamtstromes nach Öffnen des Schalters},
    xlabel = {t in s}, 
    ylabel= {$i(t)$ in mA},
     xmin = 0, xmax = 0.0050,
     ymin = -10, ymax = 10,
    xtick distance = 0.0005,
    ytick distance = 2,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!0.25},
    width = \textwidth,
    height = 0.5\textwidth]
        \addplot[
        domain = 0:0.005,
        samples = 300,
        smooth,
        thick,
        orange,] {exp(-1266.77*5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x))))*(6.3*cos(deg(5508.55*5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x)))))+1.5*sin(deg(5508.55*5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x)))))};
        
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



%%%i(u_c(t))

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title = {Verlauf des Gesamtstromes nach Öffnen des Schalters},
    xlabel = {t in s}, 
    ylabel= {$i(t)$ in mA},
     xmin = 0, xmax = 0.0050,
     ymin = -10, ymax = 10,
    xtick distance = 0.0005,
    ytick distance = 2,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!0.25},
    width = \textwidth,
    height = 0.5\textwidth]
        \addplot[
        domain = 0:0.005,
        samples = 300,
        smooth,
        thick,
        orange,] {exp(-1266.77*x)*(6.3*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+1.5*sin(deg(5508.55*x))};
        
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a parametric plot like the one you are linking to, you have to use the first function as the x component and the second function as the y component.

> (u_C(t), i(t))

With your function this results in plotting the function pair

```
({5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x)))},
 {exp(-1266.77*x)*(6.3*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+1.5*sin(deg(5508.55*x))}
)
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel = {$u_C(t)$ in V}, 
    ylabel= {$i(t)$ in mA},
    xtick distance = 2,
    ytick distance = 2,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!0.25},
    width = \textwidth,
    height = 0.5\textwidth]
        \addplot[
        domain = 0:0.005,
        samples = 300,
        smooth,
        thick,
        red,]
        ({5+exp(-1266.77*x)*(-5*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+10.3*sin(deg(5508.55*x)))},
         {exp(-1266.77*x)*(6.3*cos(deg(5508.55*x))+1.5*sin(deg(5508.55*x))}
        );
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!